# Why does $http's callback not know about variables outside of itself?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Say for example I have the following code:

```
for(var i=0; i < itemlist.length; i++){
    var item = itemlist[i];
    var id = item.id;
    $http.get(id + '.json').success(function(data){
        //do something with data.
        console.log(item.name);
    }
}
```

The name displayed in the console will be a repeated value (I think the first value in the array itemlist), i.e. the callback function doesn't know about the variable item.

With my level of understanding this is *strange*. Is there a way to pass in additional variables to this callback function - and/or - could someone enlighten me on why the scope of this variable behaves in this way?

Comment: it should be closed on that just fine.

Comment: [Creating closures in loops: A common mistake](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake) & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming itemlist is an array, you can use [angular.forEach()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) like

```
angular.forEach‎ (itemlist, function (item, i) {
    var id = item.id;
    $http.get(id + '.json').success(function (data) {
        //do something with data.
        console.log(item.name);
    })
})
```

The problem as I pointed out in the comment is wrong use of closure variable in a loop.

If you wants to [support only IE9+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Browser_compatibility) then, you can even use [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) like

```
itemlist.forEach‎ (function (item, i) {
    var id = item.id;
    $http.get(id + '.json').success(function (data) {
        //do something with data.
        console.log(item.name);
    })
})
```

Comment: ...or maybe `itemlist.forEach(function(item, i) {...});` [is supported well enough](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.forEach)?

Comment: @JanTuroň yes... in my current project I need to support IE8+ so I always ends up using those library functions....

Answer (score 0):

to associate a value with a callback function you should make use of bind.
This way you can attach any object to callback and access it via this.object:

```
function yourFunction() {
    for(var i=0; i < itemlist.length; i++){
    var item = itemlist[i];
    var id = item.id;
    var onSuccess = onSuccess.bind({item: item});
    $http.get(id + '.json').success(onSuccess);
```

}

```
 function onSuccess(data) {
    console.log(this.item.name);
}
```